# Why don't the child elements fill in the parent ones?

Tags: ios, swift

There is a scrollView with an orange background, it has an image with a white background, a gray label and a button.
ScrollView fills the entire screen, including the status bar.
How can I make the image also go to the status bar, and not be attached to its bottom?

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),

            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1000),

            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor),
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)

        ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over to your favorite search engine and search for `UIScrollView contentLayoutGuide frameLayoutGuide`

In order to get your content to scroll, you need constraints to the scrollView's`.contentLayoutGuide`.

To size the content correctly - such as to fill the width of the scroll view so we have only vertical scrolling - you need Leading and Trailing constraints to the scrollView's `.frameLayoutGuide`.

Compare your constraints to this:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

        image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        
        image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        
        // make the image view the Width of the scroll view
        image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
        
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor),
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1000),

        // make the label the Width of the scroll view
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),

        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor),
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),

        // make the button the Width of the scroll view
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
        
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        
    ])
```